# Java, Arrays, Methods

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

The below method calls are giving error while compilation. I'm unable to understand why is it so. I'm passing the same parameters as defined in the method. Kindly help.

ms_div( B[mid_i], mid_i );
ms_div( C[mid_j], mid_j );

Code Starts Below:

```
void ms_div(int[] A, int nbr)
        {
            if (nbr > 2) 
            {
                int mid_i = A.length / 2;
                int mid_j = A.length - mid_i;
                int[] B = new int[13];
                int[] C = new int[13];

                //create left hand array
                for(int i;i<=mid_i - 1;i++)
                {
                    B[i] = A[i];
                }

                //creating right hand array
                for(int i = 0,j=mid_i;i>= mid_j - 1;i++,j++)
                {
                    C[i] = A[j];
                }

                //Sort Left Hand Array
                if (mid_i >= 2)
                {
                    ms_div( B[mid_i], mid_i );
                }

                //Sort Right Hand Array
                {
                    ms_div( C[mid_j],mid_j );
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: The error message is : The method ms_div(int[],int) in the type Sorting is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)

Comment: In `ms_div( C[mid_j],mid_j );`, the first argument `C[mid_j]` is an `int`, not an `int[]`...

Comment: @AbhinashKumar https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recursive steps, you send integers to ms_div. If you send the whole array it will compile.

So instead of

```
ms_div( B[mid_i], mid_i );
```

Do this:

```
ms_div( B, mid_i );
```

And same this for the `ms_div( C[mid_i], mid_i );` call.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, feel free to mark it as 'Accepted'

Answer (score 1):

In sort Left Hand Array and sort Right Hand Array, you have to change int value to array. you should use like

```
ms_div( B, mid_i );
```

and

```
ms_div( C, mid_i );
```